# When do we use import react

Tags: reactjs

So this question might be similar but this does not answer my question "[why to import React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568791/why-to-import-react)"

When do we use `import React from react`?

I have seen certain functional component example where people pass in props and does not use JSX.

props probably pass from parent to child hence they don't need to write import but is JSX the only reason for using import react in functional component?

Similarly we used Stateful component, with `class abc extends component` when we need to use lifecycle hooks and add state?

Comment: if you are not returning a `jsx` and returning just a string or a number for example, that's just a plain function isn't it? for example: ``const Hello = ({name}) => `Hello ${name}` `` and use it like this: `<Hello name="john" />`

Comment: I seem to read different reasons why it's being done, your question seems to be a bit on the random side, could you give more info about why you have this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React` has to be in scope for Babel to do its magic, so you have to either import React or somehow declare it as a global variable.